# Не получается импортировать пакет с github

Tags: golang, импорт

Я только начинаю изучать golang. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, не получается импортировать пакет с github. Я проверил GOPATH, папку src/github.com и оказалось, что все установилось верно, но в проекте почему то импорт не работает. В чем может быть причина?

[image: Error]

```
import(
 "fmt"
 "github.com/fxsjy/gonn/gonn"
)
```

Команда go get, предлагаемая средой, срабатывает успешно, к слову.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но возможно нужно включить vgo (Go Modules). В Goland это можно сделать через "Settings"->"Go"->"Go Modules"->"Enable Go Modules Integration"

Comment: Сначала не помогло, но когда я перезашел в среду разработки все встало на свои места. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если без модулей запускать, то проект должен лежать в GOPATH